# How to install Tkinter to Aptana Studio 35-32 (Non-Eclipse)

Tags: python, tkinter, tcl, tk-toolkit, aptana3

Neither IDLE nor the IDE for Aptana Studio 3 seem to work when I try to "from Tkinter import *".
The PATH to the application shows .../Python35-32/ then I can look into Lib/tkinter but this does not seem to be a good installation as I cannot seem to find an executable for tk. Any help on how to insure a proper installation of tcl/tk and ability to import from Tkinter is appreciated. I'm using Windows 7 Pro OS.

Comment: what system - window, linux, osx ?

Comment: for python2.7 it is `Tkinter` and python 3.0+ it is `tkinter` is that the issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you are trying to import **T**kinter and then looked into Lib/**t**kinter which was present and I'd assume fully working but with a lower case **t**, in python2.7 the module is spelt with a capital and in python3+ it is with lower case, to import it in either case you can use:

```
try:
    from tkinter import * #v3
except ImportError:
    from Tkinter import * #v2
```

Comment: Thanks. That was it.